# Visual Studio will not save changes VC++ to Resource file

Tags: c++, resources

I have a legacy MFC application that I am updating to work on windows 10. This application is a C++ app originally developed with VS 6.0. Over the years it has been updated to VS 2005, then 2010, and now I am trying to use VS 2019. All is well with the code base, but I am having issues with the resource editor.

Whenever I try to update or change any object using the resource editor(dialogue versioning, et al), I cannot save it. I cannot even save it with a different name.

Google searches indicate that this has been observed when either the Autosave option is set and an element in a dialogue has the "Help ID" value set to true. After an extensive review, nothing in my dialogue has that Help ID value set to tru.

So, thinking that there is an issue with the .rc file, I have tried all of the recommendations from other posts but no matter what I do, I cannot make changes in the resource editor and save them.

I have tried this with VS 2005, 2010, and 2019. All without any luck in saving the .rc file

I went as far as opening the .rc file in a text editor, commenting out the entire .rc except the base versioning information, reloading it into the resource editor, and trying to save it. Still fails.

I am out of ideas as to what or where the root cause could be coming from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your project for read-only files? If nothing is working, remove the resource files from the project, create new resource files and restore the information from old ones step by step.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: ZDF: yes, I checked the directory and it is NOT read-only. Paul: The only error is the little box that states "Cannot save file". I will attempt the solution ZDF suggested of removing the .rc file, and creating anew one from scratch

Comment: Found the issue: in the .rc file, at the beginning, there is a section called "TEXTINCLUDE". This will reference the resource.h file. The string it was using was "\resource.h\0", while it should be "resource.h\0". The beginning "\" was causing the issue. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Devs have been reporting this error since at least **VS2012**. *"Cannot save file"* for certain `.rc` changes is still with us at **VS2022 17.4.0 Preview**. I think they have lost the source code after they bought it from you-know-who in 2007.